Python Stubs for dynamic generated class
I have a class that is dynamically generated starting from a dictionary: the output is a tree in which each leaf is an object of the class Item. Each Item can have 0 or multiple children (other Items).
For example, starting from this dict:
folder_struct ={
    "my_file": "file.csv",
    "invoices": {
        "inv_part_1": "inv_part_1.csv",
        "inv_part_2": "inv_part_2.csv",
        "inv_part_3": "inv_part_3.csv",
        "invoices_previous": {
            "old_invoices": "old_invoices.parquet"
        }
    }
}

the tree has the following structure:
U: invoices
U:   inv_part_1
U:   inv_part_2
U:   inv_part_3
U:   invoices_previous
U:     old_invoices
U: my_file

and can be accessed as following:
D = initialize(folder_struct)
D.invoices.inv_part_1.url
D.invoices.inv_part_1.read()
D.my_file.do_something()

Since each leaf is added a runtime, the IDE is not able to check which attributes and methods are available, and therefore no suggestion/docstring/syntax_errors_check can be perfomed when the debugger is off.
Is there a way to add the needed type information of the "future" structure of the class, even if the code as not been run?

Technically not impossible: you are already creating objects dynamically; you just need to generate some stub code to go with it. If by "the IDE" you mean VSCode, then Pyright/Pylance should be able to read the generated stub files with the correct settings. Do you actually want to do that, though? Won't it be easier to do .get_directory('invoices').get_file('inv_part1')?

If you can generate the stub, you can probably generate static source code for the class instead of defining the class at runtime.

Yes, it would be easier, but in a real use case there would be multiple nested directories, so the code would be a sequence of .get_dir("foo").get_dir("bar").get_dir("baz")... losing the readability. I would like to test the stubs-way before to totally change approach. thanks
